# Возможно ли прописать свое value в input type file?

Tags: javascript, fileupload

Возможно ли добавить свои файлы в `input type=file`? Имеется ввиду, что записывается в `value`, когда файлы были добавлены? Т.к. мне нужна возможность менять файлы, которые я буду отправлять (У меня идет drag'n'drop и при drop'e файла я создаю свой массив в который сохраняю fileList и нужно узнать, что из этого массива пойдет в value).

Comment: Это запрещено из соображений безопасности

Comment: "возможность менять файлы, которые я буду отправлять" - остановимся и попытаемся представить, что бы произошло, если бы это было возможно. Какой смысл Вы вкладываете в слова "менять файлы"?

Comment: Если я правильно понял вам нужно сделать дроп файла и чтобы потом он установился в поле input. Но не совсем понятен момент с массивом. Ответ дал ниже. Надеюсь это вам поможет

Comment: Так как не совсем понятно как у вас там все организованно, возможно если вы приведете пример своего кода, то получится сделать конкретное решение для в вашей ситуации.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sup>*Перевод [данного ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47515232/how-to-set-file-input-value-when-dropping-file-on-page)</sup>

<sup>*Это возможно если у вас есть dataTransfer или объект FileList</sup>

**Раньше**, Программное изменение файлов через поле `input[type=file]` было отключено из соображений безопасности но это исправлено в современных браузерах.

Firefox, последним из основных браузеров, добавил возможность, позволяющую нам установить файлы для input полей типа file. Так же согласно [**W3C тестированию**](https://github.com/w3c/web-platform-tests/pull/6617), это осуществимо в Google Chrome.

Соответствуюзий скриншот и текст из MDN:

[image]

> Вы можете установить, а также получить значение HTMLInputElement.files во всех современных браузерах. 
>   *Смотри совместимость здесь [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file#Browser_compatibility)*

В Firefox [обсуждениях ошибок и исправлений](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1384030) есть [**демо которое вы можете посмотреть**](https://output.jsbin.com/vaxagel) И также [исходный код если вы хотите это поредактировать](https://jsbin.com/vaxagel/edit?html,css,js,output). Снизу представлен исполняемый код из этой ссылки:

```js
let target = document.documentElement;
let body = document.body;
let fileInput = document.querySelector('input');

target.addEventListener('dragover', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  body.classList.add('dragging');
});

target.addEventListener('dragleave', () => {
  body.classList.remove('dragging');
});

target.addEventListener('drop', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  body.classList.remove('dragging');
  
  fileInput.files = e.dataTransfer.files;
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
}

body.dragging::before {
  content: "Drop the file(s) anywhere on this page";
  position: fixed;
  left: 0; width: 100%;
  top: 0; height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 0, .3);
  pointer-events: none;
}

button, input {
  font-family: inherit;
}

a {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,400i,700" rel="stylesheet"> 

  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  
  <h1>Drag and drop files into file input</h1>
  
  <p><small>Supported in <a href="https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/2861">WebKit and Blink</a>. To test, drag and drop one or more files from your operating system onto this page.</small></p>
  
  <p>
    <input type="file">
  </p>

</body>
</html>
```

---

> **Важно:**
>
> Вы можете сделать это только если у вас есть объект `FileList` или `dataTransfer` который вы можете установить для элемента входного файла(так как метод не принимает строки в виде обычно текста).
>
> Для больше информации смотрите здесь: [How to set File objects and length property at FileList object where the files are also reflected at FormData object?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47172409/584192)

Небольшой пример как установить значение для input после того как файл будет сброшен:

```
document.querySelector('.селектор-вашего-поля-для-дропа')
    .addEventListener('drop', (ev) => {
        ev.preventDefault();
        document.querySelector('.селектор-вашего-input-елемента').files = ev.dataTransfer.files;
    });
```